# Downgrade and Upgrade IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

Is there a way we can upgrade/downgrade IE version from Javascript code. Manually we can do using `Developer tool` by pressing `F12`.
I need to upgrade the IE Version to run Jquery Code snippet and then again downgrade.

Is there a way we can write some scripts on the page to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you're asking if you can:

1) Dynamically change the document mode to a higher emulation level,
2) Run code for the higher level level, and then
3) Return to the previous document mode:

I'm afraid that answer is also 'No'.  There is no JavaScript interface for changing the document mode on the fly.

Document mode is a rendering setting that's set while the page is loading; once it's rendered, you can only change the document mode by reloading the page (and fiddling with the environment)--which resets page contents.

What you can do, however, is:

1. Load an intermediate page at the higher document level.
2. Run the process that returns the data using the newer feature.
3. Open a second document as a lower document mode.
4. Manipulate the DOM of the second document to incorporate the data results from Step 2.

The solution could be as simple as adding a <div> to the second page and manipulating its `textContent`, `innerText`, or `innerHTML` property (depending on the document mode in question.)

Or something along those lines.

It's hard to be more specific without a clearer idea of what the underlying problem really is.

As yet another alternative, there may be a shim or polyfill for the jQuery feature that runs at the lower document mode. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) for help finding polyfills.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To be specific i have to get alternate of ` var sbr = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` as it gets prompt everytime users want to use this feature. Also client do not want to disable from IE settings. Any suggestion to get this feature enable without prompt in IE version 5.0 ?

Comment: I was thinking about the way you suggested in the answer. How to open a new page at higher end in the background (User do not want to see this page) and pass some FileSystem API related detail, process and send back resoponse back to the original in lower document mode ? Kindly guide.

Comment: Opening hidden pages is specifically blocked to prevent malicious abuse.  
The security prompt for the FileSystemObject call comes from similar work.  

Basically, the intent is to alert the user to hidden windows or potentially sensitive file access.  

In corporate environments, you can use GPO to enable/disable [feature control keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx), but I don't recall which would apply here. 

I've also heard VB can help in some cases, but don't have an example for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking if you can change the user's browser via JS. The answer to this is definitely 100% no.